# How do I delete the first part of a string in python

Tags: python, string

Hello all I have a program that is dealing with accounts and their associated names for example my username is user1234 and my real name is Bob Realname the data is store as `"user1224 : Bob Realname"` so far my program strips it down to `user1234 Bob Realname` what I would like to do is get rid of the part that says user1234 and just get the result Bob Realname.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would split the original string on `':'` and then take the second half:

```
original.split(':')[1]
```

e.g:

```
>>> original = "user1224 : Bob Realname"
>>> original.split(':')[1]
' Bob Realname'
>>> original.split(':')[1].strip()  # remove leading whitespace.
'Bob Realname'
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using `split` and `strip`.

```
>>> 'user1224 : Bob Realname'.split(':')[1].strip()
'Bob Realname'
```